# C++ Merge Sort Count Comparison

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

I am working on a project that asks us to implement different sorts and add counter variables to measure the runtime with different array sizes. My problem is that my current output is not matching the expected output for my Merge Sort. Its only off by a bit.

Any suggestions on what is wrong?

Output:

```
Array Size:          10         100         1000         10000
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Merge sort           19          569         9275       129630
```

Expected Output:

```
Array Size:          10         100         1000         10000
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Merge Sort           19         550         8706         120355
```

Whats inside the contents of the array for array size 10

```
Merge sort

[ 935, 942, 697, 299, 382, 579, 408, 181, 366, 505 ] //unsorted
[ 181, 299, 366, 382, 408, 505, 579, 697, 935, 942 ] //sorted
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
      /******************************/
      /* Start of Merge Algorithm   */
      /******************************/

 /**
  * The maximum size of the temporary array
  */
const int MAX_SIZE = 10000;

int count = 0; //I added this global variable but It seems Incorrect

/**
 * Merges two sorted array segments theArray[first..mid] and
 *    theArray[mid+1..last] into one sorted array.
 */
template<class ItemType>
void merge(ItemType theArray[], int first, int mid, int last) {
    ItemType tempArray[MAX_SIZE];  // Temporary array
    // Initialize the local indices to indicate the subarrays
    int first1 = first;            // Beginning of first subarray
    int last1 = mid;               // End of first subarray
    int first2 = mid + 1;          // Beginning of second subarray
    int last2 = last;              // End of second subarray
    // While both subarrays are not empty, copy the
    // smaller item into the temporary array
    int index = first1;            // Next available location in tempArray
    while ((first1 <= last1) && (first2 <= last2)) {
        // At this point, tempArray[first..index-1] is in order
        if (theArray[first1] <= theArray[first2]) {
            tempArray[index] = theArray[first1];
            first1++;
            count++; //I incremented count here
        }
        else {
            tempArray[index] = theArray[first2];
            first2++;
            count++; //I incremented count here
        }  // end if
        index++;

    }  // end while

    // Finish off the first subarray, if necessary
    while (first1 <= last1) {
        // At this point, tempArray[first..index-1] is in order
        tempArray[index] = theArray[first1];
        first1++;
        index++;
    }  // end while

    // Finish off the second subarray, if necessary
    while (first2 <= last2) {
        // At this point, tempArray[first..index-1] is in order
        tempArray[index] = theArray[first2];
        first2++;
        index++;
    }  // end for

    // Copy the result back into the original array
    for (index = first; index <= last; index++) {
        theArray[index] = tempArray[index];
    }
}

/**
 * Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int mergesort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        // Sort each half
        int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;

        // Sort left half theArray[first..mid]
         mergesort(theArray, first, mid);

        // Sort right half theArray[mid+1..last]
         mergesort(theArray, mid + 1, last);
        // Merge the two halves
        merge(theArray, first, mid, last);
    }
    return count; //return count here
}


      /******************************/
      /* Start of Sorting Benchmark  */
      /******************************/
/**
 * Generate an array of random integers
 */
int* makeRandomArray(int n, int seed) {
    srand(seed);
    int * a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){
    const int seed = 9000;
    int *a;
    /******************************/
    /* Start of Merge Sort    */
    /******************************/
    std::cout << "Merge sort";

    int n = 10;
    a = makeRandomArray(10, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< mergesort(a, 0, n-1);
    delete[] a;

    n = 100;
    a = makeRandomArray(100, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< mergesort(a, 0, n-1);
    delete[] a;

    n = 1000;
    a = makeRandomArray(1000, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< mergesort(a, 0, n-1);
    delete[] a;

    n = 10000;
    a = makeRandomArray(10000, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< mergesort(a, 0, n-1)<<std::endl;
    delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: Reset `count` between runs. 569 = 19 + 550. 9275 = 19 + 550 + 8706. Etc.

Comment: set count = 0;? , tried it in different places in the program but it seems to just reset the count back to 0 and makes the number of comparisons smaller, less than the expected output

Comment: Set `count = 0;` between runs (after each `delete[] a;`).

Comment: ah that works,Thank you,  but is there a way to set count to where its not a global variable and still use it

Comment: Add it as the return value (or output parameter) to `merge` and `mergesort`. Declare it and initialize it to 0 in `mergesort`.

Comment: Will try that, Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Welbog can you leave an answer so I can mark it as the answer, so future users can see the answer.